# When I call facebook authorize:permissions it keeps asking to allow the application

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I am using the facebook-ios-sdk. I am basically getting facebook from the appDelegate and everytime It hits my viewController it calls this method:

```
- (void)openFacebook{
    appDelegate.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"11234567892515" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        appDelegate.facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        appDelegate.facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![appDelegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"user_likes", 
                                @"read_stream",
                                @"user_photos",
                                //@"user_about_me",
                                //@"email",
                                @"publish_stream",
                                @"publish_actions", 
                                nil];
        [appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
        NSLog(@"Facebook session is valid"); 
        [appDelegate.facebook extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
    } 




}
```

The problem is.... even if the app is allowed it still comes up with dialog to allow the application...

How can I stop it from popping up everytime asking me to authorize the app even though I hav e already authorized it? Please keep it simple I am no genius thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you aren't storing the AccessToken and ExpiryDate once you've logged in.

Add this to see if you have these stores in UserDefaults

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"%@", [defaults dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

In your Facebook fbDidLogin method do you have like this?

```
// Store session info.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: it was pretty much this. I wasnt checking the facebook access token and expiry date correctly. cheers.